# Clear multi divs with jquery

Tags: jquery

Quick question. If i am trying to clear multiple divs with the same class all at once is there a jQuery short cut to doing this? I tried `$('.clearit').empty();` and that does not seem to work at all (none on the divs with that class are being cleared). Could I be doing this wrong or does this just not work? Let me know, I tried `$('.clearit').html('');`. Also I have this along with other code that runs after it in jquery and everything else runs as it should. I debugged the code and it seems to run the function and move on with no errors but the div content is not cleared. Here is a sample of the divs:

```
<center><div class="clearit" id="container2">Loading the player ...</div></center>
</li>
<li>
<center><div class="clearit" id="container3">Loading the player ...</div></center>
</li>
<li>  
<center><div class="clearit" id="container4">Loading the player ...</div></center>
```

and here is the code for one of the handlers. Please note everything in there works except for the `$('.clearit').html('');`.

```
$('.thumbNav li a').click(function(){
    $('.clearit').html('');


var str = $(this).html();
var pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
var matches = str.match(pattern);
var myInteger = parseInt(matches);
//variable for player
var container = "container"+myInteger;
var what = 'skill'+myInteger;
var location = "https://aliahealthcare.com/videofetcher.php?id=skill"+myInteger;
player(container,what,location);  

$('#'+what).attr('selected', 'selected');   


    });
```

To anyone still helping me, THANKS SO MUCH! also i have modified the site so you no longer need a login to get in so you can see it in action for yourself. Please use the code above as reference in finding the javascript. (It is all located in vid.php) Thanks

https://aliahealthcare.com/vid.php

Also i just discovered something interesting. The li's above are part of a ul with in id of slider. When i do `$('#slider').html('');` or `$('#slider').empty();` It works but it clears all the div thus the players that load inside those divs dont load. All i need to do is just clear the players so you cant have multipul players running at the same time.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/HwRfW/ It's not that complicated. Maybe you're not loading in jquery properly, or what Bryan Downing said in his answer, on that note, example with document ready written in the code http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/HwRfW/1/.

Comment: This code runs with other jquery code and all the other code seems to run properly

Comment: Try to debug your code and most probably it is not working because element is undefined. Put "debugger;" anywhere in your code and run your code while your firebug is kept opened.

Comment: the demo works great, thanks! However it is not working for my. I am putting $('.clearit').html(''); with other code in a handler and everything seems to work except this and the debugger was no help as it ran that line with no issue yet the divs were never cleared.

Comment: see here for the actual page https://aliahealthcare.com/vid.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see working **demo** here: http://jsfiddle.net/TxR8K/

**updated** from your given code: http://jsfiddle.net/TxR8K/1/

by the way your unordered list tag i.e. `ul` is missing in the sample :)

**Update further** after discussion with OP - we also found out - the player is actually not part of the html in the div, hence he/she knows what needs to be done and clears his./her way for further fix :)

This should do the trick

```
   $('.clearit').html('');
```

Comment: @user860869 :) no worries: made a demo again from your code :http://jsfiddle.net/TxR8K/1/

Comment: the demo works great, thanks! However it is not working for my. I am putting `$('.clearit').html('');` with other code in a handler and everything seems to work except this and the debugger was no help as it ran that line with no issue yet the divs were never cleared.

Comment: Hiya @user860869 , no problem we will fix it, can you please copy paste your code and paste your jsfiddle here :) I am heading out for a quick grab but will take a look once back, cheerios!

Comment: I posted a link to the page, please see my edit and https://aliahealthcare.com/vid.php

Comment: @user860869 cool I am back - so in your click event: `$('.thumbNav li a').click(function() {` where is class `.thumbNav` I cannot see in the source of your page? might be thats the issue :) since the click event is not binder properly.

Comment: It is the numbers on the bottom the 1-25 (so click the little tabs)

Comment: also i put the code in other handlers, also the other code in that handler works when i click there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12427/discussion-between-tats-innit-and-user860869)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is most likely that you're running that command before the DOM has loaded. Open a console window in StackOverflow and run `$("div").empty();`. Everything disappears!

Comment: I clear the divs when someone clicks something on the page such as the next button on a slider.

Comment: You should post the code for the event handler, and check the items outlined in thecodeparadox's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're code should work properly.

Please check that

- you place you code within `$(document).ready(function() {...})`, in short `$(function() {..})`
- you're loading you **jQuery library** properly
- don't have any typos mistake

If everything is OK, then your code should work.

If not then try with **@Tats_innit** answer.

#### According to you edit

### Still I think  your code should work.

but if not then you can try this:

```
$('div[id^=container].clearit').empty();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U29nv/)**

Comment: again the debugger fires this line of code, with no errors, and moves on. Yet the divs retain their content. Thanks

Comment: For a while now I've been thinking that there might be a typo, but since that should show up in console and OP hasn't reported about that, I think it's just a matter of targeting the elements properly, but your new edit seems a bit excessive.

Comment: @user860869 I think you might want to use `console.log()` to make sure that proper elements are found i.e. `console.log( $('.thumbNav li a') )` and same for the `.clearit` and see if those actually exist

Comment: Thecodeparadox, you are targeting `div` that has `ID` that begins with `container` and also has class `clearit` and by no means should that make targeting the right element easier or work, if targeting just the `.clearit` doesn't work. Making the targeting more strict surely won't help...

Comment: I posted a link to the page. Please see https://aliahealthcare.com/vid.php thanks!